# Java doesn't render display table

Tags: java, css-tables

Our teacher asked us to make an example of monolithic app using java and display table.
Here the program:

```
public Main() {
    super("Project X");
    super.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<html>");
    sb.append("<body>");
    sb.append("<div style='border: 2px'>");
    sb.append("<h1> Almanacco astronomico </h1>");
    sb.append("<h2> Novembre 2018 </h2>");
    sb.append("<p> <b>Il Sole.</b> <i>In Novembre perderemo complessivamente 1 ora e 3 minuti di luce.</i></p>");

    // create a table
    sb.append("<div style='display:table'>");   

    // create a row
    sb.append("<div style='display:table-row'>");

    // create a cell
    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");  
    sb.append("Data");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");
    sb.append("Sorge");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");
    sb.append("Tramonta");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("</div>");//close div row 
    // create a row
    sb.append("<div style='display:table-row'>");

    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");  
    sb.append("1gio");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");
    sb.append("6:55");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");
    sb.append("17:10");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("</div>");//close div row 
    sb.append("<div style='display:table-row'>");

    // create a cell
    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");  
    sb.append("2ven");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");
    sb.append("6:56");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("<div style='display:table-cell'>");
    sb.append("17:08");
    sb.append("</div>");

    sb.append("</div>");//close div row 

    sb.append("</div>");//close div table
    sb.append("</div>");//close container
    sb.append("</body>");//close body
    sb.append("</html>");

    // DONE Convertire lo StringBuilder in String
    String htmlText = sb.toString();
    // DONE Assegnare correttamente la stringa create a JLabel
    super.add(new JLabel(htmlText));
    super.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println(htmlText);   
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
```

I noticed that java doesn't render css, in fact if I run there aren't a table but only a vertical list of table-cell content. There is a way to render the table?
PS. Java doesn't even render border:2px

Comment: Is this a `javax.swing.JLabel`?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you are sure that your teacher want you to create an html table with swing (I guess cause of JLabel)?

Comment: yes i'm sure. But java doesn't render css

Comment: Maybe [this](http://esus.com/applying-css-to-an-html-rendered-jlabel/) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JLabel` does not support `CSS 2.x` visual formatting model.

Then HTML4 `style=""` attributes and CSS box formatting wont work.

There is a partial support of CSS in swing, you can have a look into the supported CSS elements [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html)